# Tipo de valor Static en un objeto en C#

Tags: c#

Hola tengo una duda con mi código que tengo acá lo uso para guardar un inventario mando todo el objeto a una clase donde esta toda la lógica. he estado investigando más el tipo de valor static, lo que he encontrado es que mi código está mal porque el atributo Products en su get y set lo he encapsulado en un atribulo static que es privado _Products entonces cada vez que instancio el objeto si tengo una operación en proceso con este objeto se sobre escribirá con los nuevos datos ingresados. La idea es que cada objeto sea independiente. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

```
public class InventoryEntity
{
    public InventoryEntity()
    {
        this.Products = new List<DetailEntity>();
    }        

    public int Id { get; set; }

    private static List<DetailEntity> _Products;
    public List<DetailEntity> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _Products;
        }
        set
        {
           _Products = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hice fue remplazar ese código por este otro como dije en la pregunta anterior no se si estoy en lo correcto. Gracias por su ayuda.

```
public class InventoryEntity
{
 
public int Id { get; set; }

public List<DetailEntity> Products { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las propiedades estáticas pertenecen a la clase y no a ningún objeto de este tipo, por esta razón, todos las instancias de la clase comparten los miembros estáticos de esta, por tanto, el cambio que se hace a un miembro estático puede ser visualizado desde todas las instancias de la clase.